# How it follows that $a=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a \in \mathbb F$ is a scalar and $v \in V$ is a vector and I prove that if $av = 0$ then $a=0$ or $v=0$ I argue like this: Assume $a \neq 0$. Then multiplyaing both sides with its inverse implies $v=0$. Assume $v \neq 0$. Then how to deduce that $a=0$ from $av=0$? Is it possible?

Comment: You just proved that, if $av=0$, then either $a=0$, or $v=0$. What is left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked about proving that $(av = 0, v \ne 0) \Rightarrow a = 0$ using only linear algebra, which I assume means "simpler than shown above". I hope you find this helpful.

Let

$$v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0, \quad v_i \in \mathbb{F}.$$

Since $v \ne 0$, there exists $k$ such that $v_k \ne 0$. Since

$$av = \begin{bmatrix} av_1 \\ av_2 \\ \vdots \\ av_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0\!,$$

for such $k$ we have

$$a v_k = 0.$$

Since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, it has no [zero divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), so you may now conclude that $a = 0$ (the same way you concluded that $a \ne 0$ means that $v = 0$).

Answer (score 6):

You have proven the statement:

$a \ne 0 \implies v = 0$

The contrapositive of this statement is

$v \ne 0 \implies a = 0$

The two statements are logically equivalent, so you really have already proven what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Is it possible to prove $v \neq 0 \implies a=0$?

Comment: @blue I assume you want a "direct proof". I don't know how familiar you are with the concepts of ring theory, but here goes: the set $\{a\in F:av=0\}$ is an ideal of $F$ that does not contain $1$. Because $F$ is a field, that ideal must be $\{0\}$.

Comment: @user1 Thank you, it is what I was asking. Is it not possible to prove it only using linear algebra? If you post the comment in an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @blue Honestly, what I wrote is a rearrangement of the parts of the proof by contradiction/contrapositive you already have seen--one acquainted with the relevant theory can see how the proof of the fact I stated is essentially $a\ne0$ implies $a^{-1}$ exists. I personally think the answers you have already are better than my comment(s).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prove (under certain hypotheses) that either condition $A$ or $B$ holds (and possibly both), then one possible approach is to assume that $A$ does not hold, and show that this implies that $B$ holds, in other words establish that $\lnot A\Rightarrow B$. This suffices to prove $A\lor B$, and indeed is logically equivalent to it. So you don't need to separately prove $\lnot B\Rightarrow A$, that is just *another* logically equivalent way to say $A\lor B$.

This applies to your question with $A\equiv(a=0)$ and $B\equiv(v=0)$. In other words after showing $(a\neq0)\Rightarrow(v=0)$ you should just stop the proof; you're done.

Comment: But assume I wanted to prove $\lnot B \implies A$. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course that is possible. A trivial way is that logically $(\lnot B\Rightarrow A)\iff(\lnot A\Rightarrow B)$ so you can use the second part (which you already proved) as proof for the first. If you find this cheating, you can assume $v\neq0$ and prove $a=0$ by contradiction (assume $a\neq0$ etc.) which really amounts to the same. It happens that here $(a\neq0)\Rightarrow(v=0)$ is really the most natural form of the proof, but logic allows you to turn things around in various ways.